# Get text from clipboard in Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

When trying to get text from clipboard using [`Clipboard.GetText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28VS.95%29.aspx) method  in a Windows Phone app, it always throws a `SecurityException` (intended behaviour).

Is there any hack or workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you meant to link to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28VS.95%29.aspx) where it says:

> You cannot get clipboard text from a Windows Phone application, only
>   set it. Calling the GetText method in a Windows Phone application will
>   always cause a SecurityException to occur.

There's a blog post [here](http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2011/01/how-scratchpad-does-copy-and-paste.html) on how a developer 'faked' copy/paste within an app and shared it across apps. There are couple of limitations with the method and if you want to share it across apps then all the apps have to support this method. If you want to be able to write to a clipboard and use it anywhere on the phone, then it's not possible. If it was possible, throwing the `SecurityException` above would be pointless and any hacked workaround would most likely result in rejection of the app from the Marketplace.